# What does the `new` keyword do

Tags: java, new-operator

I'm following a Java tutorial online, trying to learn the language, and it's bouncing between two semantics for using arrays.

```
long results[] = new long[3];
results[0] = 1;
results[1] = 2;
results[2] = 3;
```

and:

```
long results[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

The tutorial never really mentioned why it switched back and forth between the two so I searched a little on the topic. My current understanding is that the `new` operator is creating an object of "array of longs" type. What I *do not* understand is why do I want that, and what are the ramifications of that?

- Are there certain "array" specific methods that won't work on an array unless it's an "array object"?
- Is there anything that I *can't* do with an "array object" that I can do with a normal array?
- Does the Java VM have to do clean up on objects initialized with the `new` operator that it wouldn't normally have to do?

I'm coming from C, so my Java terminology, may not be correct here, so please ask for clarification if something's not understandable.

Comment: `long[] results = {1, 2, 3}` is just a special syntax in Java that's short for `new long[] {1, 2, 3}` which is itself just short for `long[] results = new long[3]; results[0] = 1; results[1] = 2; results[2] = 3;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Java, all arrays and objects are allocated on the heap, so in a sense, all arrays are "array objects". The only things that are ever allocated on the stack in Java are object references and primitives. Everything else is an object that is defined and allocated in the heap, including arrays, regardless of which syntax you use to declare it. (Your two examples are equivalent in the end result, see [JLS §10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3) and its linked sections for more on how each one is actually allocated and assigned.)

This is contrary to C/C++, where you have explicit control over stack and heap allocation.

Note that Java is very fast when it comes to short-term object allocation/deallocation. It's highly efficient because of its generation-based garbage collector. So to answer your questions:

> Are there certain "array" specific methods that won't work on an array unless it's an "array object"? Is there anything that I can't do with an "array object" that I can do with a normal array?

There is no such thing as an array that's not an object, so no. There *are*, however, methods which won't work on primitive arrays. A method that takes an `Object[]` will not accept a `long[]` without first converting it to `Long[]`. This is due to some implementation details of autoboxing in Java 5 and up.

> Does the Java VM have to do clean up on objects initialized with the `new` operator that it wouldn't normally have to do?

Anything allocated with `new` must eventually be garbage collected, so in terms of doing anything it wouldn't *normally* do? No. However, note that in C/C++, allocating an array using `malloc`/`new` means you also have to `free`/`delete []` it, which is something you *don't* have to do in Java since it will reclaim the array for you.

Note that if your `long[]` is declared in a method, and you never store it in a reference somewhere outside of your method, it will be marked for garbage collection automatically at the end of the method call. The garbage collector will wait to reclaim its space until it needs it, but you don't have to do any reclamation yourself via `delete []` (or `delete` and destructors for objects).

**Edit:** some references as promised:

- [How Garbage Collection works in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html)
- [<strike>Oracle</strike> Sun white-paper on garbage collection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/memorymanagement-whitepaper-1-150020.pdf)

Comment: That's interesting... didn't know that about the allocation of objects. So we don't have to "free" objects allocated to the heap due to automatic clean up of the Java VM, is that correct?

Comment: @Mike Correct, the garbage collector will automatically free anything that no longer has a reference to it.

Comment: @Mike Absolutely correct. See my latest update. You have to reclaim space yourself in C++ via `delete`. You don't need to do this in Java because of its automatic garbage collector, which uses a [reference graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046761/) to determine which variables can still be accessed via some "root" in the garbage collector that will never be reclaimed (exists in the "permanent generation"). I'll see if I can find a good reference for it in case you're interested in reading more about it.

Comment: @Mike I've added a couple references, take a look.

Comment: +1 Excellent article about garbage collection and a good answer as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The `new` keyword in Java creates a new object.  In this case it is creating an array ... which is an object.

Those two forms are equivalent.  The second one is just a convenient shorthand for the first one.  It is *syntactic sugar*.

> Are there certain "array" specific methods that won't work on an array unless it's an "array object"?

All arrays are objects.  Period.

> Is there anything that I can't do with an "array object" that I can do with a normal array?

See above.

> Does the Java VM have to do clean up on objects initialized with the new operator that it wouldn't normally have to do?

No.  There is no difference between the objects created in different ways as far as the JVM is concerned.

Comment: Yeah, the fact that all arrays are objects in Java makes the rest of the questions kinda moot points. I had assumed that there was a "static" allocation for arrays when the `new` keyword was not used.

Answer (score 5):

The two are identical in terms of the behavior of the array created. All arrays are technically objects in java; these are just two different ways initializing them. Also its possible to combine the two like so:

```
long[] results = new long[]{1,2,3};
```

Answer (score 3):

The both are same. The second option is doing implicit creation of array object, it is just for user convenience.

Answer (score 3):

From [`JLS#Chapter 10. Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html)

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.

From [`10.3. Array Creation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3)

> An array is created by an array creation expression (§15.10) or an array initializer (§10.6)

From [`15.10. Array Creation Expressions`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10)

> An array creation expression creates an object that is a new array whose elements are of the type specified by the `PrimitiveType` or `ClassOrInterfaceType`.

From [`10.6. Array Initializers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10)

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration (§8.3, §9.3, §14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), to create an array and provide some initial values.

**Both are initialize the array the difference is second one initializes with some values.**

Comment: +1 good references to the JLS. I'll make sure to look there as well for answers.

Answer (score 1):

The two ways of creation that you've shown are equivalent. Both are "array objects" - remember, everything in Java (with the exception of the basic numeric types like `int`, `double`, and so on) are Objects. The second is simply shorthand for the first, much in the way that C has a similar shorthand for stack allocated integer arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The following two code snippets are equals in compiling level.
I write a Demo class like:

```
public class NewArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long results[] = new long[3];
    }
}
```

and

```
public class NewArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long results[] = {0,0,0};
    }
}
```

output of 'javap -c NewArray' is exactly the same:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_3
   1:   newarray long
   3:   astore_1
   4:   return

}
```

long results[] = new long[]{1,2,3}; and long results[] = {1,2,3}; are exactly the same too.

So,although sometimes you are not using new key word,but the compile will regard them as equal.

Comment: +1 good point about the default values provided by the constructor. In C `long results[3]` would have undefined elements, nice to know it's 0 when making an array object.

Answer (score 1):

The 'new' keyword creates an array. Now, depending on what type of data the array is for the values inside of it vary. If you declare the array as an integer and use the 'new' keyword then it will contain the values 0 unless you change the values inside. With a String it will contain the value 'null'. In every single space.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you create an object.

In first version:

```
long results[] = new long[3];
results[0] = 1;
results[1] = 2;
results[2] = 3;
```

you say in first line that array size is 3. Then you put values into the array.

In second version:

```
long results[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

You create the same array and initialize it in the same line. Java computes, that you gave 3 arguments and makes the `new long[3]` without Your help :)