# How HashMap handles the updated <key,value>,if value itself is a Hashmap?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm, out-of-memory

when we put a `<key,value>` in a HashMap,if the key is already present in the HashMap then the value gets replaced. But if for a key the value is itself a HashMap then would it get replaced with the HashMap?

Comment: "What"? Can you show some sample code or explain this "error" in more detail? From the tags, it sounds like the concern is a "circular reference" (which isn't a concern in JVMs as they will correctly GC any object that is not *strongly reachable*); however, it could be the case that the object(s) in question are always strongly reachable and thus never reclaimable ..

Comment: Nothing special happens.

Comment: The first value will only get replaced if the two HashMaps (keys) are equal. Otherwise you will have two different entries in the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to know if what you just said will cause a memory leak (please update your question if this isn't what you're asking).

If you do:

```
Map<?, ?> m = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
m.put(m, m);
```

Then `m` will ultimately only contain a reference to itself. Because of how Java's GC works via an object reference graph, and because they use an algorithm which tracks visited nodes during a GC sweep, if nothing maintains a reference to `m`, then `m` will be garbage collected, despite containing a reference to itself. Circular references are perfectly handled in the Java GC.

If `m` is placed into a *field* (i.e., *not* a local variable declared inside a method) then it's a different story.

- If `m` is placed in a `static` field, then there will always be a reference to it from a GC root, which means it won't be reclaimed. Note: nothing strongly referenced to from a `static` field will ever be garbage collected.
- If `m` is placed in a member field (non-`static`), then the map won't be garbage collected until the object that contains it is garbage collected.
- If there are multiple fields that refer to `m`, then `m` won't be garbage collected until *all* those references are either a) part of an object that can be garbage collected or b) are set to `null` or some other value to no longer refer to `m`.

**TL;DR** the garbage collector handles circular object references just fine.

*Sidenote:* Please update your *question* with information, don't just add it as comments to your question or others' answers.

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926518/what-does-the-new-keyword-do/13926592#13926592) for some GC reference material.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it would be replaced. Remember that a Map only stores references to other objects.

You put a reference to a HashMap in a map, and the map keeps a reference to this HashMap.

If you put a reference to another HashMap using the same key, the reference to the first put HashMap is replaced by the reference to the new HashMap. The type of the object doesn't matter. It always works the same way.

Comment: private static Map<key,value> m =new HashMap<key,value>; is an instance variable of a class value and key is an interface.In the Synchronized(m){m.put(this,this);},the values are being populated. the scenario is the HashMap already have the HashMap entries of 63 Elements as the value of a key, now for this key the value is Hashmap entry of 64 elements, According to me for this key now only 64 entries of HashMap should be there But both 63 entries and 64 entries are present in Heap which i analysed through the Eclipse MAT.

Comment: Edit your question with real code. But `m.put(this, this)`, where `this` is a mutable HashMap, will obviously cause problems. Keys should be immutable. If their hashhCode changes while stored in a HashMap, the HashMap won't work correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I stongly suspect this is the reason for memory leak for my application. Kindly explain this,how to rectify this mutable key and what should i change to rectify my HashMap? Thanking you again

Comment: I can only rectify code that I see. You haven't shown us your code.

Comment: I am not suppose to paste the code here as this will become an integrity issue and they will throw me out of this organization. i tried a work around, I removed the static from map and i changed the hashCode as a constant. Now it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

The wording in your question is a bit opaque, but a `HashMap<HashMap, Object>` is perfectly valid (if somewhat strange).  In that case, if:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap<HashMap<String, String>, String>();
HashMap a = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap b = new HashMap<String, String>();  //a.equals(b) == true

map.put(a, "foo");  //map.get(a) would now return "foo"
map.put(b, "bar");  //original entry is replaced, map.get(a) would now return "bar"
```