# Passing string array values directly to setter method

Tags: java, arrays, string

There's a String array that I have which has setter and getter methods. How do I directly pass values `{"one", "two"}` to the setter method rather than setting the values to a variable first and then passing the parameter?

```
String[] arr1 = {};
public String[] getArr1() {
    return arr1;
}

public void setArr1(String[] arr1) {
    this.arr1 = arr1;
}
```

..expecting something like `setArr1(?);`...

Comment: Thanks all!! `setArr1(new String[]{"One", "Two"});` is working fine!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `setArr1(new String[]{"one", "two"})`

Alternatively, you could make use of varargs and change your method signature to 
`setArr1(String... values)` and use the method as `setArr1("one", "two")`

Answer (score 2):

```
someobject.setArr1(new String[]{"One", "Two"});
```

Please refer [`my answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926518/what-does-the-new-keyword-do/13926588#13926588) on arrays for more info on array intialization.

Answer (score 2):

```
setArr1(new String[]{"one","two","three"});
```

Try like this

Answer (score 1):

try this - `setArr1(new String[]{"one", "two"})`

Answer (score 0):

use this code
this is setter method

```
public void setSubTaught(int pos, String value)
{
    subjectsTaught[pos]=value;
}
```

this is getter method

```
public String getSubTaught()
{
    String sub = Arrays.toString(subjectsTaught);
    int len = sub.length();
    String fix = sub.substring(1,len-1);
    return fix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  `setArr1(String[] arr1)` is taking array of string as a parameter so you can set as normal way we set setter methods.

```
yourObject.setArr1(new String[]{"string1", "string2"});
```