# New Operator Internal memory allocation in heap

Tags: java

How new operator allocates memory for the object in **Java**? it was asked what happen if we write 
**Test t= new Test().** 
How the new operator will work to allocate memory internally in heap memory? Might be some steps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926518/what-does-the-new-keyword-do

Comment: I understand, but did not get any suitable ans, if you know then please ans.

Comment: This is NOT the site for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is JVM dependant. There is a number of possible outcomes.

- if the object isn't needed, it might be eliminated i.e. nothing happens.
- if Escape Analysis detects the object doesn't escape a method, it can place it on the stack.  This allocation happens when the frame is started and all the memory needed is reserved at once (not per object)
- if you have TLAB (Thread Local Allocation Buffers) enabled (which is by default), each thread has a local buffer from which to allocate objects.  This allows concurrent memory allocation.  It has a pointer the next free space in the buffer and when a new object is added it takes the pointer and adds the size of the object.  It zeros out the object as well (and sets up the object header). New buffers are allocated from the Eden space (except in G1 where it gets an empty chunk of memory)
- if you don't have TLABs, allocation is taken directly from the eden space.

Comment: Thank you for sharing Knowledge.@peter